# Getting no display of the output when inserting a node in a BST

Tags: tree, insert, binary-search-tree

I want to insert a 'new' node in a binary search tree. But on running the code, I am either getting errors such as :

```
an infinte loop (with nothing as display) 
 temp.data(nonetype) has no value.
```

Can you see what's the error in this code and how to rectify the same.

Please see my following code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data=0):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
class tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
    def insert(self,data):
        temp = root
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.left = None
        new_node.right =None
        while temp.left and temp.right:
            if new_node.data < temp.data:
                temp  = temp.left
            else:
                temp = temp.right
        if temp.data > new_node.data:
            temp.left = new_node
        else:
            temp.right = new_node
    def display(self,temp):
        if temp == None:
            return
        else:
            print(temp.data,end = " ")
            self.display(temp.left)
            self.display(temp.right)        
if __name__=='__main__':
    mylist = tree()
    root = Node(19)
    root.left =Node(12)
    root.right = Node(30)
    mylist.insert(10)
    mylist.display()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not take in consideration when a node has only left or right subtree. While iterating through the nodes you need to check if your left or right child is None type or not.
I have modified the tree class to initialize root in constructor.
Modified Code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data=0):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
class tree:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
    def insert(self,data):
        temp = self.root
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.left = None #remove this as it will be set to none in Node constructor itself. 
        new_node.right =None #remove this
        while temp.left or temp.right:
            if new_node.data < temp.data:
                if temp.left != None:
                    temp  = temp.left
                else:
                    break
            else:
                if temp.right !=None:
                    temp = temp.right
                else:
                    break

        if temp.data > new_node.data: 
            temp.left = new_node                   
        else:
            temp.right = new_node
    def display(self,temp):
        if temp == None:
            return
        else:
            print(temp.data,end = " ")
            self.display(temp.left)
            self.display(temp.right)        
if __name__=='__main__':    
    root = Node(19)
    #root.left =Node(12) #insert using insert function of tree class
    #root.right = Node(30) 
    mylist = tree(root)
    mylist.insert(12)
    mylist.insert(30)
    mylist.insert(10)
    mylist.insert(20)
    mylist.insert(18)
    mylist.insert(9)
    mylist.display(root)
```

Comment: how does this answer OP's question?

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain me what is meant by this line :  self.root = root

Comment: Just initializing the root node in constructor. Once the tree object is created, we can refer root node within the class with : self.root. You were using the root as a global variable and i have initialized it in class constructor so that each tree object can have a root node of their own. Now you can create multiple tree objects and initialize their root node. To display we can use something like this: mylist.display(mylist.root). similarly it can used for other tree objects without using the variable.